# Regarding git diff

Tags: git

How can I view the differences in a specific file using git diff command for the following scenarios?

1. difference in a specific file between workspace and staging area;
2. difference in a specific file between workspace and local repository;
3. difference in a specific file between workspace and remote repository.

Answer (score 1):

1. difference in a specific file between workspace and staging area

   ```
   git diff path/to/file
   ```
2. difference in a specific file between workspace and local repository

   ```
   git diff HEAD path/to/file
   ```
3. difference in a specific file between workspace and remote repository.

   ```
   git diff origin/master path/to/file
   ```